# Entity Framework: How does the data context deal with duplicate objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So today I discovered that c# passes reference types by value by default. This ran counter to what I thought I understood - reference types are by reference as standard. Oh well.

This led me to think about a method that I had that took an entity object as a parameter, attached to a context, and made some changes to it. The method did not return the object. When calling save changes on my context, the changes made within the method were applied.
I assumed at the time that it worked because I was passing a reference to the object and so could happily alter it without having to return anything to reassign.

So the question is, how does this work? (the code did work as I expected).

Thanks,

Comment: I discovered that c# passes reference types by value by default! Can you show where did you find this?

Comment: You haven't grasped the concept correctly. Here's an [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this stuff is tricky.  I've found myself not thinking about it for a few months, and then having to think about it for a few seconds to get it straight in my head again.  Even though I've understood it for a long time.

Even though the **parameter** is by value, that just means that a new reference variable is created, but still *pointing to the same object*.  If you make the parameter by reference, then the same pointer would be passed in, which of course points to the same object.

It makes a difference when you mess with the parameter variable.  If you set it to null or to some other object, the variable "outside" will not be affected.  But if the parameter was passed in by value, then setting the variable to null or another object will alter the reference "outside".

For a value type, whether the parameter is by reference or by value makes a practical difference more often.  Changes to the value or to a member (if it's a struct) will not be reflected "outside" if passed by value.

Here's a [good explanation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) with easy examples.

Comment: thank you for the reply (all of you). makes total sense. now, like you say, I just have to remember that for the next time I have to think about passing by value and reference!

Answer (score 1):

Reference types in C# are passed by reference. Which means when you pass a reference type only reference is passed to that method not the actual value

When you pass a reference type object to a method you are actually passing a new reference/pointer to that object

Let's understand by example

```
SomeRefType myRef = new SomRefType();
//above myRef is reference to object of SomRefType type
//pass this reference to a method
SomeMethod(myRef);

SomeMethod(SomeRefType reference)
{
   //here reference is a new pointer/reference pointing to same object as myRef
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *reference* is passed by value (ie the reference is copied not the target object) - it is still a reference to the same object. This is as opposed to passing by reference, where the original reference is passed around.

Hopefully this illustrates the point:

```
var myObject = new object();
PassByValue(myObject);
Console.WriteLine(myObject == null); // returns false. The fact the method changed its *copy* of the reference to null doesn't affect the caller.

PassByReference(ref myObject);
Console.WriteLine(myObject == null); // returns true. We actually passed in our reference itself, not a copy of the reference; so when the method set it to null, it nulled the reference we held in the caller.

void PassByValue(object obj)
{
  obj = null;
}

void PassByReference(ref object obj)
{
  obj = null;
}
```